# AWS Cloudformation configure ICMP protocol for the security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How do I use CloudFormation to create a security group to allow "ALL ICMP"

Type: All ICMP

Protocol: All

Port range: N/A

Source: 0.0.0.0/0

I tried the following but it gives "echo reply". What is the correct syntax for "ICMP all"?
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "FromPort": "0",
                    "IpProtocol": "icmp",
                    "ToPort": "-1"

Answer (score 3):

[AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html) has a code sample to **Allow ICMP Ping**:

```
"SGPing" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "DependsOn": "VPC",
  "Properties" : {
    "GroupDescription" : "SG to test ping",
    "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "VPC"},
    "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ 
      { "IpProtocol" : "icmp", "FromPort" : "8", "ToPort" : "-1", "CidrIp" : "10.0.0.0/24" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Strangely, the page also suggests using `-1` for the `FromPort`.

Comment: So the problem was they were using same port for from and to port?

Answer (score 3):

In Cloudformation (CFN) this will allow all ICMP traffic:

```
"IpProtocol" : "icmp", "FromPort" : "-1", "ToPort" : "-1", "CidrIp" : "10.0.0.0/8"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following syntax ?

Type: All ICMP 
Protocol: TCP
Port range: 0 - 65535
Source: Anywhere - 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Yes, but those are instructions for the console. The OP requested syntax for Amazon CloudFormation.

Comment: { "IpProtocol" : "icmp", "FromPort" : "8", "ToPort" : "-1", "CidrIp" : "10.0.0.0/24" }

Comment: This is incorrect. ICMP and TCP are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

In [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html) Cloudformation resources, the [fromPort](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-ingress-fromport) and [toPort](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-ingress-toport) attribute take on different functionality when the ICMP protocol is selected because ICMP does not have ports like TCP or UDP does.

When ICMP is selected as the protocol, the fromPort attribute becomes the icmp type number and the toPort attribute becomes the icmp code. When -1 is used for these values it represents all codes or all types. With that in mind, your cloudformation template would look like

```json
"SGPing" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "GroupDescription" : "SG to allow all ICMP",
    "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "VPC"},
    "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ 
      { 
        "IpProtocol" : "icmp", 
        "FromPort" : "-1", 
        "ToPort" : "-1", 
        "CidrIp" : "10.0.0.0/24"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here's a list of all ICMP types and codes https://www.iana.org/assignments/icmp-parameters/icmp-parameters.xhtml